# Why is regex always true or always false

Tags: c, regex

I am trying to use a regex to determine if a provided file has the .csv extension.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>

int match(const char *string, const char *pattern) {
    regex_t re;

    if (regcomp(&re, pattern, REG_EXTENDED|REG_NOSUB) != 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    int status = regexec(&re, string, 0, NULL, 0);
    regfree(&re);
    if (status != 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

int main(void) {
    const char *reg = "^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]{1,}(.csv)$";

    if (!match("test.csv", reg)) {
        printf("Not a valid csv file.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Valid csv file.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that with `match(...)`, anything evaluates to true. If, on the other hand, I try `!match(...)`, anything evaluates to false. So, what is wrong with my code? I want only .csv evaluate to true, everything else to false.

Examples (and the desired result):

- test.csv = true ("Valid csv file.")
- test.abc = false ("Not a valid csv file.")

Comment: If `match` is always true then `!match` will always be false... I think your question is why doesn't this regex match `.csv` correctly.  Also, bear in mind this does nothing to prove whether or not something is a 'valid csv file' only that the extension is .csv

Comment: Where is your error handling? What did your debugger tell you? Do you even know which `return` statement was executed?

Comment: You should use `"^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\\.csv$"`

Comment: You should make `match` to return different values for different errors. Now we don't know whether it is failing because it is not matching or because of some error.

Comment: Out of interest, what's wrong with checking if the final characters are `".csv"`?

Comment: To be honest, I find the concept of validating the extension misguided anyway,  you should check that the file contents are valid not that the filename is valid.

Comment: I'd recommend using an online regex tester like regex101.com - easy to hash out issues and see components of your expression - but this pattern in particular is a valid regex there, allowing the `-` before the end of that character class definition, which is the main issue here.

Comment: The code posted here is just an example. In my real code I am checking the file contents to determine if it is valid CSV. My goal, however, is to check the file extension before checking the content. If the extension is not .csv, the file is invalid anyway and there is no reason to even begin checking its contents.

Comment: @ci7i2en4 lots of apps will save csv files with a .txt extension. And of course extensions are mutable anyway... I'd just skip the extension check entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you are using is not valid for the regex flavor: the hyphen must be used at the start/end of the bracket expression. Also, you need to escape the dot, else, it will match any char.

Use

```
const char *reg = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\\.csv$";
```

See the [C demo](https://ideone.com/DH1raB).

Comment: I would also suggest using a better error handling mechanism (use defines to differentiate between the cases `CSV file`, `not a CSV file` and `regcomp error`).

Comment: Yes, this code can be improved more, I'd compare the `status` value against `REG_NOMATCH` for readability. The current issue is not the code, however.

Comment: Thank you, Wiktor! With your regex, my code finally seems to be doing what it's supposed to do. However, I did use an online regex checker myself and my regex got the desired results, too. Only in my code it didn't work properly ...

Comment: regexec() returns "0" if the pattern matching was successful, REG_NOMATCH if it wasn't. So I think checking for either result is fine?!

Comment: @ci7i2en4 It is fine, just it adds to readability to use dedicated constants, that's 
 just IMHO.